# Generate a heterokskedastic series in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to generate a heteroskedastic error term in MATLAB.

I have found a good link to help [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/258485/simulate-linear-regression-with-heteroscedasticity/258510#258510), the problem I am having is replicating this in MATLAB.

Here is my attempt:

```
n = [(1:100) (1:100)]';
sigma2 = n.^(1.3);
t = size(n,1);
for i = 1:200
    eps(i) = normrnd(0, sqrt(sigma2(1)));
end
eps = eps'
h = archtest(eps)
```

However, the test for hetero indicates I still do not have heteroskedastic data, can anyone see where I am going wrong.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to have anything to do with the one you linked. You are currently generating normally distributed random numbers, nothing else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're keeping sigma2 fixed in the first value inside the loop.

Replace

```
eps(i) = normrnd(0, sqrt(sigma2(1)));
```

with

```
eps(i) = normrnd(0, sqrt(sigma2(i)));
```